# Volume of cube with faces laying flush with planes

Tags: calculus, geometry

The cube has faces laying flush with planes:

$$P_1 = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x + 2(y-3) + 2z = 1\}$$
$$P2 = \text{the plane parallel to $P_1$ but containing point }(2, 2, 2)$$

I'm not really sure what it means for the cube to have faces laying flush.

Comment: I guess it means one face is on $P_1$ and the opposite face is on $P_2$. Isn't there more data for the cube?

Comment: No that was all the data that was given. I'm not sure how to calculate the volume of a cube given its 2 faces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flush means the entire side is touching the plane, not just one point of it.  It's like a cube sandwich, and the planes are the bread.

If you know how far apart the two planes are, you then you know how long one side of a cube is.

If you have a plane equation $Ax + By + Cz = D$, and call vector $V$ as $\begin{bmatrix} A & B & C \end{bmatrix}$, then the distance of the plane to the origin is $\frac D {|V|}$ where $|V|$ is the length of $V$.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. I found the equation for P2, and then calcuated the distance between the 2 planes which gave me the length of the cube's side.